# Rails 3, acts-as-taggable-on gem - how to get the most used tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tags, count, acts-as-taggable-on

I use [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem and  would like to fetch 5 most used tags, how could I fetch them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your controller must be:

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
    def tag_cloud
        @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags).limit(5).order('count desc')
    end
end
```